# Acyclic component graph

Tags: c++, graph, depth-first-search

I have a c++ graph implemented using an adjacency list. I have correctly working functions for DFS and for finding the transpose of the graph. How would I print out only the acyclic portion of the graph?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "the acyclic portion of the graph?"

Comment: Basically I would like to find and remove all the cycles in a given directed graph leaving the graph with no cycles

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could do is: Whenever your DFS hits a node you've already checked before (indicating a cycle), delete the edge you just traversed.